# Passing html Table data in viewbag

Tags: html, model-view-controller, html-table, viewbag

I have some data in a database which I am collection in a control function. I place the returned values in to a structure as below:

```
For I As Integer = 1 To Mygallery.Length - 1
    With Mygallery(I)
        Select Case True
            Case Counter = 0
                Line &= "<tr><td><a href=""" & .Dir & """><img src=""" & .GalleryImage.ToString & """ alt=""" & .Customer_Name.ToString & """ height=""200"" width=""150""/> </a></td>"
                Counter = 1
            Case Counter = 1

                Line &= "<td><a href=""" & .Dir & """><img src=""" & .GalleryImage.ToString & """ alt=""" & .Customer_Name.ToString & """ height=""200"" width=""150""/> </a></td></tr>"
                Counter = 0

            Case Else

        End Select
    End With
Next
ViewBag.galleryLine = Line
```

As you can see I add this to a `ViewBag.galleryLine` item. In my html view page I then reference this    `table style="width:100%">@ViewData("Table")` table
(Had to remove the html code as I could not get it to show)

Anyway the problem is it does not write it as a table but as text!

if I put the text that the viewbag returns straight in to the view it displays correctly. So it not a formatting issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Html.Raw method, like this

```
@Html.Raw(ViewData("Table"))
```